# Pushing to browser history on a failed request does not render expected component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a basic handler that will attempt to refresh a user's login via a token. I used [the following guide](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md) to implement it.

```
function redirectToLogin() {
  const redirectUrl = encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
  browserHistory.push('/login', { query: { redirectUrl } });
}

async function refreshToken(options) {
  try {
    return await request(REFRESH_URL, options);
  } catch (e) {
    redirectToLogin();
  }
}
```

this does update the window location, as I am at `/login` after visiting the page. However, it does not render the appropriate component at that route.

If I reload the page, it does render the correct component. I tried catching the error and dispatching an event in an attempt to "force" a re-render, however, it still does not trigger the expected re-render.

Why isn't the component rendering on navigation?